# report module for sugarcrm 6.2

Tags: reporting, sugarcrm

Which Report module is suitable for making reports in sugarcrm 6.2 . I had installed the zucker Report Module on the local site it works properly but when i used to install them on my server it does not installed

Anyone please help

Thanks

Comment: Just bumped into this, have you found a decent reporting module since you posted this question?

Comment: Did you make it work on your server?

Comment: when i used to install zucker report module at my server it doesnt installed properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest KINAMU Reporter, http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/kinamureporter

Answer (score 1):

KReporter certainly the best Reporting tool in the Marketing for SugarCRM, regardless of edition - be it PRO, ENT, CORP or CE.

The new free Google Charts are really cool